# Need help pulling an int from an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int[] codes = { 39835, 72835, 49162, 29585, 12653, 87350, 74783};

    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}

        private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random mRandom = new Random();
            int randcode = mRandom.Next(0, codes.Length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pull a random code from the array by clicking "btnRandom" and compare it to a string but "int randcode" always comes up as an error when i try it.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {
      if (txtCode.Text == randcode) ;
      {
          MessageBox.Show("working");  
      }
   }
```

Trying to get it to work like this.

Comment: button1_Click cannot access randcode, because that variable is scoped as local to the btnRandom_Click method.

Comment: When you get an error, it is helpful to post the actual error text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems:

- Your `codes` array contains integers. Your textbox contains a string.
- You are not actually accessing the array when you do the compare - you're comparing an integer index to a string.
- You have a semicolon after your `if` statement that shouldn't be there.
- `randcode` is not defined at the class level, so you can't access it from a different function than the one it was declared in.

In short, you want something like this:

```
int randcode;

private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random mRandom = new Random();
    randcode = mRandom.Next(0, codes.Length - 1);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (txtCode.Text == codes[randcode].ToString()) 
   {
       MessageBox.Show("working");  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have either to parse `txtCode.Text` to integer or convert `randCode` to `string`:

```
if (int.Parse(txtCode.Text) == randcode) ...
```

or

```
if (txtCode.Text == randcode.ToString()) ....
```

But there are some things you can/must fix:

1. In `Random.Next(min, max)` method, `max` is exclusive, so the call must be like this:

   ```
   int randcode = mRandom.Next(0, codes.Length);
   ```
2. You are declaring ranCode inside `btnRandom_Click()`, and must be in `Form1` class:

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       int randCode;
       int[] codes = { 39835, 72835, 49162, 29585, 12653, 87350, 74783};

   ....

   randcode = mRandom.Next(0, codes.Length);
   ```
3. And you have a `;` after the `if` statement, so `MessageBox.Show("working");` will be executed no matter the result.

Finally the code should be like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int randCode;
    int[] codes = { 39835, 72835, 49162, 29585, 12653, 87350, 74783};
    ...

    private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random mRandom = new Random();
        randcode = mRandom.Next(0, codes.Length);
    }
    ...

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.Parse(txtCode.Text) == randcode)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("working");  
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thats because txtCode.Text is a string and randcode is an integer. YOu cant compare these two. They must both be strings or ints. Try this

```
if(txtCode.Text == randcode.ToString())
```

I also note that int randcode is not in scope in this method. You meed to mkae randcode a member variable by declaring it at class scope